# Using object across C# & C++ COM Interop

Tags: c#, c++, .net, outlook, interop

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am developing an Outlook plugin that utilizes a C++ with a MAPI backend. My MAPI knowledge is fairly basic, I'm using the MSDN and a book that was written in 1996 so not much talk of C# in there!

I have a communication layer that is written in C# and accessed via a Connector object. It (the connector) is interfaced and registered for interop. It is accessed in the Outlook plugin (also C#) and the C++ (MAPI using `CreateInstance(CLSID)`)

Essentially I want to have the same Connector object available to both the C# & C++. Currently I am trying to make use of a Singleton instance by doing this:

C++:

```
Manager.CreateInstance(Manager::CLSID_Manager);
Manager->GetConnector(&m_Connector);
```

C#:

```
public IStoreConnector GetConnector()
{
    Connector.GetInstance();
}
```

As there isn't any direct communication with the MAPI backend and the C# plugin, the C# also creates its own instance of the manager object to try and get the same instance:

```
private Manager.Manager manager = new Manager();
private Connector connector = manager.GetConnector();
```

It successfully creates the objects as expected but adding to a list via C++ was not being reflected in a counter in a message box created via C#.

I'm assuming that it is down to the C# and C++ being in different address spaces and so the getInstance() calls do not have reference to the same instance?

I'm trying to have the C++ add a reference to a file into the connector then have the C# have access to the same list the C++ just added to.

Any advice or link to a well written guide would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you can call managed C++ from your unmanaged C++ code I'd suggest two possible approaches:

1. In you unmanaged C++ abstract your managed instance via void* and you can pass it as a handle in between your unamanged C++. When passing it to managed C++ code you can upcast it to your managed object. The singletone pattern is managed using standard .NET implementation. This is good only if all your codes are running within the same process.
2. If you have multiple processes or just want a different approach, you can implement you .NET code as COM server (advised MTA, but you can do STA as well, especially if you need sequential access). Then Win32 cares to provide you a single instance of the COM server.

Comment: As you mention in 1. I think the problem I'm having is because my references to the classes are not all within the same process. If I create a COM server with C# would I still just CreateInstance() in the C++ and use new COMServer() in the C# to get reference to the same object in both?

Comment: Yes, it's because creating instance you'r actually creating a proxy to your service. If you don't have experience with COM server-client, there is plenty of materials on the internet. .NET allow you creating COM server using assembly and class attributes